# Chaining Hash Tables - Average number of table entries examined when adding to hash table

Tags: data-structures, hash, hashtable, formula

I know that in chained hashing, the average number of table entries
examined in a successful search is approximately:

```
1+(load factor/2)
```

Would it be the same formula for the number table entries examined when adding elements to the hash table? I'm thinking it would be. Just want to make sure I'm not thinking about this wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No.  If you're doing a successful search, then of the N elements linked from the bucket you hash to, you'll on average visit ***half*** of them before finding the element you want.  But, the average length N is not the load factor.  For example, with a load factor of 1, 1/e ~= 36.8% of buckets can be expected to be empty, just as many to have one element, half that with 2 elements (~18.4%), a third of that with 3 elements (~6.13%), a quarter of that with 4 elements (~1.53%), a fifth of that with 5 elements (~0.3%), a sixth of that with 6 elements (~0.05%)....  The average is about 1.58 - considerably more than the load factor.  The reason for the discrepancy is that load factor incorporates 0s for empty buckets, but a successful search never looks in an empty bucket and therefore sees a higher average N.

When adding elements that aren't already in the table, but the hashtable insert function isn't allowed to assume they're not there, you have to compare against all N elements linked from the relevant bucket before you've confirmed the element isn't already there.  Which might seem like twice as many operations, but the Ns we're talking about may be different: for a successful search, we always hash to an in-use bucket, whereas for an insertion there's a chance we hash to an empty bucket, which reduces the average number of operations.

(If the hash table implementation provides an insert_known_new(N) function it can just append to the linked list at that hash bucket without any key comparisons with existing elements, but I've never seen a hash table provide such a function - it would hand over control of the hash table's class invariants to the user, which breaks encapsulation, though in this case justifiably in my opinion.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  "Insert" is effectively a lookup operation with an additional modification.

However, if your hashing scheme involves any kind of rebalancing or resizing operation, then there may be a higher amortized operation count for inserts than lookups.